# Rectangle collision (C++)

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-engine, collision, rect

I'm currently using this collision code:

```
( // tx = other x, tex = other end x etc.
( // horizontal collision
(xpos >= tx && xpos <= tex)
||
((xpos + w) <= tex && (xpos + w) >= tx)
)
&&
( // vertical collision
(ypos >= ty && ypos <= tey)
||
((ypos + h) <= tey && (ypos + h) >= ty)
)
)
```

However, it only detects if the top left pixel, the top right pixel, the bottom left pixel, or the bottom right pixel is within the rectangle to test. I don't know what to do, it already took forever to get to the current collision testing method I'm using, what can I change to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that one rectangle extends horizontally from *xpos* to *xpos* + *w* and vertically from *ypos* to *ypos* + *h*, and the other extends horizontally from *tx* to *tex* and vertically from *ty* to *tey*? With *w*, *h*, *tex* − *tx*, and *tey* − *ty* all being positive?

If so, then you can write:

```
xpos <= tex && xpos + w >= tx       // horizontal collision
&& ypos <= tey && ypos + h >= ty    // vertical collision
```

Alternatively, you may find it easier to reason about if you calculate the conditions whereby they *don't* collide, and just add a `!`:

```
!(
    xpos > tex             // first rectangle entirely to right of second
    || xpos + w < tx       // first rectangle entirely to left of second
    || ypos > tey          // first rectangle entirely above second
    || ypos + h < ty       // first rectangle entirely below second
)
```

(The two versions are equivalent, due to one of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).)